# Setting hash reloads page in Django

Tags: django, url, leaflet, window.location, mapbox

This is not super relevant to my question, but it gives some background: I made a map using the MapBox API. I then wanted to implement a plugin called Leaflet-hash, which basically stores your current position in the map, in the URL hash, like so:

```
http://localhost/#5/12.123/60.123
```

So whenever you pan the map, the coordinates gets updated and the hash changes. This worked fine in a separate, clean, HTML page. But when I tried using the plugin in my Django site, it stopped working.

The plugin uses `location.replace('#'+coordinates);` to update the hash. For some reason, this reloads the page within the Django framework. Also, the coordinates gets added to the URL but without the hash sign. This obviously has some unwanted effects. I have no idea what causes this behavior, but I've found that:

1. `location.replace('#')` works as expected, i.e. adds the hash to the URL without reloading the page.
2. `location.replace('#'+'randomWord')` works as expected.
3. `location.replace('#'+map.getCenter().toString())` reloads the page, with the string added to the URL, without the hash sign.
4. The same thing happens if I do `location.replace('#'+d3.version)` where D3 is a Javascript library. The page reloads.

I want to get this behavior (see the hash button): https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/toggling-ui/

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with Django, but is purely about Javascript.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any idea what could be going on here? Where would you start?

Comment: You probably want to explicitly set `location.hash` rather than using `replace`.

Comment: Same thing using location.hash :/

Comment: did you find a solution to this? How did you solve it? @trevorDashDash

Comment: Too long ago unfortunately @YoshitaArora

Answer (score 0):

Not reproducible with Django `1.7.7`, django-leaflet `0.16.0` and the latest leaflet-hash.

Everything works as expected.